# JSP how to code auto email reminder

Tags: jsp, jakarta-mail, reminders

I am doing a booking system, and need to send an email reminder to user one day before the booking date? I have no idea how to trigger send email any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **quartz schedule triggers**

Build trigger string at the time of booking and it will automatically execute on time specified.